# Saying the value is in between the other 2 values

Tags: comparatives, ielts

I'm preparing for **Ielts** test. Its writing part is the most difficult for me.

So far, I'm learning about *comparative between numbers*, and I stuck.

> - **Let's say, there was a given bar chart giving 3 bars, red, blue, and
>     orange.**
> - **The length of the blue was the longest and the orange's was the shortest**.

[image: a bar chart giving 3 bars]

This could be described as:

- The blue had *the biggest/largest/greatest/(the most)* *`number of people/(internet users)`* at 1,000 units.
- The orange had *the smallest/(the least)* *`number of people/(internet users)`* at 380 units.

---

The question is how can I *properly* and *formally* describe the **red** one which had value in between the blue and the orange **in one sentence**?

> - **Example**: The red had *greater/bigger/larger/(more)* *`number of people/(internet users)`* than the orange, and/but *smaller/(less)* *`number of people/(internet users)`* than the blue. **`(This is 2 sentences)`**

---

> - **Example**: The red had *`the number of people`* at 550 units ***`which was/as`*** the second place.
>     < **[Correct](http://#) || [Incorrect](http://#)** >

---

> - **Example**: The red had *`the number of people`* at 550 units ***`which was/as`*** in between the blue's and the orange's.
>     < **[Correct](http://#) || [Incorrect](http://#)** >

---

Any of your advice would be very helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red bar represents the ***[intermediate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/intermediate)*** quantity of the three values.

> being, situated, or acting between two points, stages, things,
>   persons, etc.

I wouldn't say that a bar on a chart *has* a number of people, rather that it *represents* or *shows* a number of people or a quantity.

Comment: About those **"*`number of people || with or without "the" article/(users)`*"** things I referred were representatives of nouns/objectives for the sentences. It was my bad that I didn't state it earlier. Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it :)

Comment: The red had **`the intermediate`** number of *`people/nouns`* *(of the (given) data)* at 550 units.

Answer (score -3):

"Median" term is used with groups or lists of numbers.
Perhaps use the symbols < >. Example: orange > red < blue

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to ELU. It's often useful to include a formal dictionary definition (a free one with a link, preferably) in an answer. "Median" has a fairly specific mathematical definition. And shouldn't that be "orange < red < blue"? That is orange is smaller than red, red is smaller than blue.

Comment: So it would be **" The red had the median *`number of people`* at 550 units. "**, right? @Pam

Comment: "Median" has a specific meaning in statistics/probability, and a specific meaning in anatomy, **neither of which are correct here**.

Comment: @Chappo Given a data set consisting of these three values, the value represented by the red bar would be the median. It's not the best word to use in this context though.

Comment: @nekomatic The best word to use in this context is the one you've offered. +1 for a good and well-presented answer :-)